# javascript onclick happening on page load

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to make a simple Javascript function to open a window with a bigger image when an image is clicked on. What happens is this test alert pops up on the page load and then does nothing when i click on the image. Here is the code

```js
function zoom() {
  alert("test!");
}
document.getElementById("us").onclick = zoom();
```

```html
<img id="us" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
```

Comment: When you add the '()' you're calling the function.  What you want to do is reference the function.  What you posted is the equiv of writing an anonymous function like so:

Comment: document.getElementById("us").onclick = (function(){})();

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
function zoom()
{
    alert("test!");
}
document.getElementById("us").onclick=zoom;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function zoom()
{
    alert("test!");
}
document.getElementById("us").onclick=function(){zoom(variable1)};
```

If you need to pass a variable.

Answer (score 4):

for es6  `onclick = () => zoom(i)` works

Answer (score 1):

why not bind the onclick with html element itself instead of doing it in javascript

```
  <img src="yourImage.jpg"  onclick="zoom()" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: sorry my solution did not appear as it was not properly edited with code tag

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("us").onclick=zoom;
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("us").onclick=zoom();
```